# Running external tools in Eclipse on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-flex, flash, eclipse, macos

I'm using Flash Builder 4 on a mac. I've created a JSFL file for building a few fla's and then testing my main SWF file. I'm trying to run this JSFL file as an external tool from Flash Builder 4 but when I select Adobe Flash CS4.app as the file to run the JSFL Eclipse warns "External tool location specified is not a file."

I have Parallels installed and if I point at a .exe file this warning goes away. Is this a bug? Why can't I use a .app as an external tool in Eclipse?

Comment: can you point to the actual file, not the package (e.g. /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CS4/Adobe\ Flash\ CS4.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe\ Flash\ CS4) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Location: `/usr/bin/open`

Working Directory: `empty`

Arguments: `-a /Applications/YourApp.app --args "arguments"`