# Is it possible to run Chrome as an external tool on Eclipse 3.6 on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome

I'm trying to set up Chrome to run as an external tool in Eclipse on the Mac. I've entered the path to Chrome as the Location variable:

```
"/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
```

I've got some arguments to pass in to Chrome, but that's not so important - I can't seem to get it started from Eclipse as an External Tool at all. The "Run" button is greyed out, and the configuration doesn't show up on the External Tools run menu once I save it. What am I doing wrong/missing?

**UPDATED**:

Attempting to use the "open" command ala [Running external tools in Eclipse on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056228/running-external-tools-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x) appears to simply switch to a running instance of Chrome, instead of run chrome with me command line arguments.

I've tried location:

```
/usr/bin/open
```

Arguments:

```
-a "/Applications/Chrome.app" --args "localhost"
```

and Chrome does not open localhost - instead it simply switches to an existing open window with Chrome in it.

Comment: It's a programming environment configuration question. I expect programmers configuring eclipse will run into this issue, and I doubt system configuration experts (superuser) would either know the answer or be interested in the question

Comment: Is it a typo, or did you miss the `-a` argument at the front?

Comment: The docs say -a, but it seems to work fine without. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this similar SO post help you?

[Running external tools in Eclipse on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056228/running-external-tools-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: It got me closer, but not close enough. My latest problem may be a Chrome implementation issue, though

Comment: Have you ever been able to get Chrome to do what you want, from the commandline for instance?

Comment: Not exactly. At best, it opens up the link in a new tab in an existing browser window. Sometimes it only changes focus to the browser, without opening up the link. As far as I can tell, this is the best that is possible with Chrome.