# Eclipse (Mac) external tool not running commands in terminal

Tags: eclipse, macos, terminal, gruntjs

I am the sole front-end developer at a company where engineers use Eclipse for all things code.  I have a great grunt build tool for the front-end code set up, and I'm fine using the commandline + text editor. However I'm trying to find a way for the other developers to be able to build and deploy the front-end code locally via eclipse.

I found this [very helpful article](http://paultavares.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/setup-an-eclipse-run-external-tool-configuration-for-grunt/) for how to use Grunt as a external tool in eclipse for windows.  However, other developers have Linux or Macs.  Another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056228/running-external-tools-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x) deals with how to run an application via eclipse external tool.  Trying to the mix the two concepts I created a builder with the following properties:

- Location: /usr/bin/open
- Working Directory: ${project_loc}
- Arguments: -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app grunt buildAndServe

However, the eclipse console complains that "The files [project dir]/grunt and [project dir]/buildAndServe do not exist."

Eclipse seems to be expecting me to call the terminal app with a list of files separated by spaces, but what I want to do is pass an argument that will run the "grunt buildAndServe" command just like I would run it from the command line in the project directory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/989349/2670892 for a discussion of running a command in Terminal

Answer (score 1):

I found how to work it. Pleaese try following setting;

- Location: Full path of your grunt ( e.g. /usr/local/bin/grunt )
- Working Directory: ${project_loc}
- Arguments: buildAndServe

Answer (score 1):

With maktag's suggestion I encountered the error message

> env: node: No such file or directory

So in addition to the settings on the *Main* tab, I added an entry on the *Environment* tab:

1. Variable = `PATH`
2. Value = `${env_var:PATH}:/usr/local/bin`